# How to get nested grid to span entire page when the parent grid has an aside

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-grid

I made a parent grid consisting of 2 columns, the one on the right is an aside.
I made a nested grid of 3 columns in the parent grid's first column.
I changed the order of the columns on smaller screens so that the aside shows up first.
It all looks ok on larger screens but on smaller screens, the nested grid columns are still behaving as though the aside is still taking up the screen. Inspect also shows that the nested columns are doing this.

I want the nested columns to span the full-width of the screen i.e across the whole parent grid, as if the aside doesn't exist.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.outer-grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
  gap: 1.5rem;
}

.outer-header {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3rem;
}

.nested-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(min(200px, 100%), 1fr));
  gap: 1.5rem;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

.articles img {
  width: 100%;
}

.articles {
  background-color: lightcoral;
  padding: 60px 20px;
}

aside {
  background-color: lightcyan;
  border-left: 3px solid black;
}

@media (max-width: 849px) {
  aside {
    order: -2;
    grid-column: span 2;
  }
  .outer-header {
    font-size: 1rem;
    order: -1;
    grid-column: span 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-grid-container">
  <div>
    <p class="outer-header">Lorem, ipsum dolor.</p>
    <div class="nested-grid">
      <article class="articles">
        <h3>Lorem</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      </article>
      <article class="articles">
        <h3>Lorem</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      </article>
      <article class="articles">
        <h3>Lorem</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      </article>
    </div>
  </div>
  <aside>
    <h2>Hello world</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto autem repudiandae quae! Autem dolorem voluptatibus perferendis! Placeat architecto tempora rem consequatur? Ipsam dolorem magni illo eum mollitia reprehenderit architecto quaerat.
    </p>
  </aside>
</div>
```

Comment: in your mediaquerie, reset also `.outer-grid-container` alike : `@media (max-width: 849px) {
  aside {
    order: -2;
    grid-column: 1/-1;
  }

  .outer-header {
    font-size: 1rem;
    order: -1;
    grid-column: span 2;
  }
  
.outer-grid-container {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
}`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you want the nested columns to span the full width of the screen i.e. across the whole parent grid.

Here, I have attached the code with some changes in order to make the nested columns to be of full-width.

Hope this will work for you.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.outer-grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
  gap: 1.5rem;
}

.outer-header {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3rem;
}

.nested-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 1.5rem;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

.articles img {
  width: 100%;
}

.articles {
  background-color: lightcoral;
  padding: 60px 20px;
}

aside {
  background-color: lightcyan;
  border-left: 3px solid black;
}

@media (max-width: 849px) {
  aside {
    order: -2;
    grid-column: span 2;
  }
  .outer-header {
    font-size: 1rem;
    order: -1;
    grid-column: span 2;
  }
  .nested-grid{
      grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
  .outer-grid-container{
      box-sizing: border-box;
      grid-template-columns: 100% 0px;
      column-gap: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-grid-container">
        <div>
          <p class="outer-header">Lorem, ipsum dolor.</p>
          <div class="nested-grid">
            <article class="articles">
              <h3>Lorem</h3>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            </article>
            <article class="articles">
              <h3>Lorem</h3>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            </article>
            <article class="articles">
              <h3>Lorem</h3>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            </article>
          </div>
        </div>
        <aside>
          <h2>Hello world</h2>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto autem repudiandae quae! Autem dolorem voluptatibus perferendis! Placeat architecto tempora rem consequatur? Ipsam dolorem magni illo eum mollitia reprehenderit architecto quaerat.
          </p>
        </aside>
      </div>
```